# Function to draw text on screen using C++/OpenGL/Glut faster than glutBitmapCharacter

Tags: c++, opengl, text, drawing, glut

I need something muuuch faster than glutBitmapCharacter(font, text[i]). It's decreasing performacne few times ! I need to display fps, xyz position etc. so not in 3D just displaying HUD.

Currently I'm using :

```
glRasterPos2f(x,y);

for (int i=0; i<text.size(); i++)
{
   glutBitmapCharacter(font, text[i]);
}
```

I'm using this function :

```
void glutPrint(float x, float y, LPVOID font, string text) 
{ 
    glRasterPos2f(x,y); 

    for (int i=0; i<text.size(); i++)
    {
        glutBitmapCharacter(font, text[i]);
    }
}
```

Every frame in DisplayFunction in drawing HUD section (calling DrawHUD()) :

```
void DrawHUD (void)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0.0, -1.0, 10.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.2f,0.2f,0.2f);

    glutPrint(2,10,glutFonts[4],its(sfps)+" fps; "+its(todrawquads)+" quads drawing; ");

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}
```

Also using int to string function :

```
string its(int i)
{
stringstream out;
out << i;
return out.str();
}
```

## some fact about performance (measured in FPS)

Without calling DrawHUD function **~ 3500**

With calling DrawHUD function **~ 3500** (maybe few less fps)

With DrawHUD + 1 x GlutPrint **~ 3300**

With DrawHUD + 2 x GlutPrint **~ 2400**

With DrawHUD + 3 x GlutPrint **~ 1700**

(eg. when I mean *3 x GlutPrint* I meant in DrawHUD :

```
{
[...]

glutPrint(...);
glutPrint(...);
glutPrint(...);

[...]
}
```

)

That's not nice ... I know measuring using frame rate isn't good.

## also

when I commented :

glutBitmapCharacter(font, text[i]);

in loop in glutPrint there was ~3500 fps ... so I'm **SURE** that glutBitmapCharacter is problem. So what use instead it :) ?

Then what to do ?

Comment: I doubt glutBitmapCharacter is a bottleneck. Please show the context in which the code is called.

Comment: Time to give up on GLUT.  Your question is too poorly documented to suggest a better library.

Comment: I'm not sure about glut, but I know in GDI etc. it's much better to draw onto a buffer and then draw the buffer.

Comment: @Mat: That's not the case here. glutBitmapCharacter just provides a little convenience around glBitmap. glBitmap itself is quite fast, but if used in the wrong context may trigger some performance impacts.

Comment: Now you have enough information , right :) ?

Comment: @datenwolf, no worries. As said I don't know much about gl.

Comment: Uhh, so what I can use instead of glutBitmapCharacter ??

Comment: Hmm, this is really strage. I don't see a reason why you should run into a OpenGL synchronization point there. What GPU do you use? Is it an AMD/ATI one? If so, then I'd be less surprised. Now others already told you to not use GLUT. I agree, but I that glBitmap would cause such a drop I didn't expect. Anyway, for testing, try out glutStrokeCharacter, doesn't look as beautiful, but does draw characters using GL_LINES http://openglut.sourceforge.net/group__fonts.html

Comment: I'm going this way, but when using glutStrokeCharacter text is reversed and like reflected in the mirror. How to fix it ?

Comment: @dj8000: By not telling OpenGL to flip the projection in the Y axis. The way you called glOrtho will flip it. swap the top and bottom parameter and make the coordinates relative to the lower left (that's where OpenGL places the screeen origin).

Comment: `glBitmap` **is** ridiculously slow.  That's why everyone uses texturing to draw bitmaps.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, go back to the basics: create your own (better) drawing function. Make a rectangular texture of characters and draw contiguous quads (triangle strips) on screen with the font texture selected, one strip per string of characters.

The above still holds fine with VBO's if you choose to go that route. The only important thing is to *buffer* the writes as much as possible, maybe by adding stuff to print to the screen to an array of sorts and writing them out at the end of the frame draw at the same time.